# change data feed on Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks, change-data-capture

I would like to use the change data feed to curate from one layer (bronze) to anotehr layer (silver) incrementally. I came accross this nice feature in databricks where you enable change feed feature and you only read the latest changes that happened to that table `delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true`. These all good but this requries to pass the version or timestamps as mentioned [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html#read-changes-in-batch-queries)! but I would like to pass this as the parameter and not as the string. Always, latest version!

Since it has the `_commit_version` column there maybe I will include the where statement where `_commit_version` is max? will this work (need to still test it myself tho?

and what happens if my curation from bronze to silver fails today at (lets say) version 3. and tomorrow there is already new version 4. which means I need to currate both versions 3 and 4. In this case how can I manage this?

I want to use `batch queries` and not `streaming queries`. I guess `streaming queries` will support above mentioned problems by providing the checkpoint location when `write.stream` happens!

Any help apprecaited

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by version?  Do you mean latest version for each row (or deleted) (which requires a row id)?  The only way to guarantee that is to either process all the version (3 and 4) or query for each row to see if there is a later change in 4.

Comment: with the version I mean the latest change feed itself. Then if I have to query entire data what is the point of using the Change Feed, the goal of this should be to process only the latest updates (meaning very small amount of data and not entire table) on the table and curate to next layer.

Comment: the change feed is a CDC feed, please read: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/06/09/how-to-simplify-cdc-with-delta-lakes-change-data-feed.html .  You don't have to process the entire table but you must process all of the differences since the last time you've processed - it can't be skipped

Comment: thats exactly what my question is, how do you track what you have process last time? in all the example I see the Start version is hardcoded, but I would like it to be dynamic eveytime I run, which means that I need to log this data somewhere in cofig table to it will pick it up from there. or how does this work? I want to currate all the new data in the silver everyday (once per day)

Comment: it'd be great if you can clarify that in your question, it wasn't clear.  The answer is you must persist the progress elsewhere, after curation mark the new progress.

Comment: so documentation saying that if you use `streaming queries` then `# not providing a starting version/timestamp will result in the latest snapshot being fetched first` , according to your asnwer I assume is not supported in `batch queries`

Comment: correct, but again, you need everything from the version you last processed which you must keep somewhere.  The highest version you can retrieve directly through either the delta table api or the table_changes function

Answer (score 0):

To pass it as a parameter, you need to store it in a variable. Unfortunately, that is not possible since the max version you will get is in a table with a column like below.

```sql
SELECT MAX(version) AS ver FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY student)
```

Output:

[image]

So, my idea is to use this query and filter it out in `table_changes`.

Code:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_changes('student', 0) WHERE _commit_version = (SELECT MAX(version) AS ver FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY student))
```

This gives the latest version records.

Output:

[image]

And use it further to curate from one layer to another layer.

Next, when it fails in between and a new version is updated, as you said, to handle such cases, you have the `checkpoint` option if it is in streaming mode. In batch mode, you need to keep a record of these changes and continue checking whenever you do your curate.

If versions are synced between one layer to another layer, you can just take the max version difference and perform your operation on the difference result you got.

Example:
In the silver layer, the max version is 2, and the same with the gold layer. Today, you got version 3 in silver and started curation. Upon failing, the gold layer doesn't have version 3, and tomorrow, silver has a new version 4. Now, if you take the difference of max versions, you will get 2, and you need to start curation from 2 versions before, from silver to gold. Once again, I am stating this only if the versions are synced and not updating the gold layer separately.